# Postgres: getting latest rows for an array of keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple table for the events log:

```
uid | event_id | event_data
----+----------+------------
  1 |  1       | whatever
  2 |  2       |
  1 |  3       |
  4 |  4       |
  4    5       |
```

If I need the latest event for a given user, that's obvious:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE uid=needed_uid ORDER BY event_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, suppose I need the latest events for each user id in an array. For example, for the table above and users `{1, 4}` I'd expect events `{3, 5}`. Is that possible in plain SQL without resorting to a pgSQL loop?

Comment: Do you actually want an **array** as result? Or whole rows in the order of elements in the input array? This would raise the more interesting question how to preserve the given order ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I need the rows, but the order does not really matter.

Comment: I added another answer anyway, there is sweet potential for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Postgres specific solution is to use `distinct on` which is usually faster than the solution using a window function:

```
select distinct on (uid) uid, event_id, event_data
from events 
where uid in (1,4)
order by uid, event_id DESC
```

Comment: Why is `order by uid, event_id`, not just by `event_id`?

Comment: @bereal: because `distinct on` requires the `order by` to start with the column(s) that are specified for `distinct on`. Try running it without it ;)

Comment: I can an error with above answer. It seems that `,` after (uid) needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

try below query :

```
select DesiredColumnList 
from 
(
    select *, row_number() over ( partition by uid order by event_id desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

`Row_Number` will assign unique number starting from 1 to each row order by `event_id desc` and `partition by` will ensure that numbering should be done for each group of `uid`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT uid,
       event_id
  FROM(SELECT uid,
              event_id,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY event_ID DESC) rank
         FROM events
      )
 WHERE uid IN (1, 4)
   AND rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To return rows in the **original order of array elements**:

#### Postgres 9.4 or newer

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM   unnest('{1, 4}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY a(uid, ord)  -- input array here
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT * FROM events e
   WHERE  e.uid = a.uid
   ORDER  BY e.event_id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) e
ORDER  BY a.ord;
```

Details for `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

There is a subtle difference to the [@a_horse's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968580/939860): If the given array has duplicate elements, this query gets duplicate rows in return, which may or may not be desirable. If it's not, add a `DISTINCT` step after `unnest()` and before the join to the big table.

The main benefit is **optimized index usage**. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Postgres 9.3 or older

Using an implicit `JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM  (SELECT '{1, 4}'::int[]) a(arr)  -- input array here
     , generate_subscripts(a.arr, 1) i 
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT * FROM event e
   WHERE  e.uid = a.arr[i.i]
   ORDER  BY e.event_id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) e
ORDER  BY i.i;
```

Comment: You, sir, rock, I have to notice.

Answer (score 0):

This came to me few seconds after I posted the question. It's not as efficient, but to consider all the options:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id IN 
    (SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM events GROUP BY uid WHERE uid IN (1,4))
```