# DISTINCT ON slow for 300000 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance, distinct-on

I have a table named assets. Here is the ddl:

```
create table assets (
    id            bigint                                 primary key,
    name          varchar(255)                           not null,
    value         double precision                       not null,
    business_time timestamp with time zone,
    insert_time   timestamp with time zone default now() not null
);

create index idx_assets_name on assets (name);
```

I need to extract the newest (based on insert_time)  value for each asset name. This is the query that I initially used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (a.name) *
FROM home.assets a
WHERE a.name IN (
                 'USD_RLS',
                 'EUR_RLS',
                 'SEKKEH_RLS',
                 'NIM_SEKKEH_RLS',
                 'ROB_SEKKEH_RLS',
                 'BAHAR_RLS',
                 'GOLD_18_RLS',
                 'GOLD_OUNCE_USD',
                 'SILVER_OUNCE_USD',
                 'PLATINUM_OUNCE_USD',
                 'GOLD_MESGHAL_RLS',
                 'GOLD_24_RLS',
                 'STOCK_IR',
                 'AED_RLS',
                 'GBP_RLS',
                 'CAD_RLS',
                 'CHF_RLS',
                 'TRY_RLS',
                 'AUD_RLS',
                 'JPY_RLS',
                 'CNY_RLS',
                 'RUB_RLS',
                 'BTC_USD'
    )
ORDER BY a.name,
         a.insert_time DESC;
```

I have around 300,000 rows in the assets table. On my VPS this query takes about 800 ms. this is causing a whole response time of about 1 second for a specific endpoint. This is a bit slow and considering the fact that the assets table is growing fast, this endpoint will be even slower in the near future. I also tried to avoid `IN(...)` using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (a.name) *
FROM home.assets a
ORDER BY a.name,
         a.insert_time DESC;
```

But I didn't notice a significant difference. Any idea how I could optimize this query?

Comment: So you have 300.000 rows. How many distinct names in the table and how many do you query? And what's your version of Postgres? This may become (much) faster, yet ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try adding the following index to your table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON assets (name, insert_time DESC);
```

If used, Postgres can simply scan this index to find the distinct record having the most recent `insert_time` for each name.

Comment: Wow, great. this is now taking only 150ms.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For more than a few rows per `name` in the table (looks to be so), I expect this query to be **substantially faster**, yet:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM   unnest('{USD_RLS, EUR_RLS, SEKKEH_RLS, NIM_SEKKEH_RLS, ROB_SEKKEH_RLS
               , BAHAR_RLS, GOLD_18_RLS, GOLD_OUNCE_USD, SILVER_OUNCE_USD
               , PLATINUM_OUNCE_USD, GOLD_MESGHAL_RLS, GOLD_24_RLS, STOCK_IR
               , AED_RLS, GBP_RLS, CAD_RLS, CHF_RLS
               , TRY_RLS, AUD_RLS, JPY_RLS, CNY_RLS
               , RUB_RLS, BTC_USD}'::text[]) AS n(name)
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   home.assets a
   WHERE  a.name = n.name
   ORDER  BY a.insert_time DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) a;
```

Pass your list as array, unnest, and then get each latest row in a `LATERAL` subquery. The `CROSS JOIN` eliminates names that are not found at all. (You might be interested in `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` instead, to keep those in the result.)

You still need the multicolumn index that Tim mentioned.

```
CREATE INDEX ON assets (name, insert_time DESC);
```

Default ascending sort order would work, too, in this case. Postgres can scan backwards:

```
CREATE INDEX ON assets (name, insert_time);
```

See:

- [Postgres: getting latest rows for an array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968384/postgres-getting-latest-rows-for-an-array-of-keys/26974716#26974716)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748) - basically type 2a
- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Not the number of rows in the table, but the number of rows *per group* (per `name` in your case) decides whether `DISTINCT ON` is the best choice. See this  benchmark comparing relevant query styles:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/34715134#34715134)